# Azure Function return object type casting

Tags: c#, azure-functions

Trying to understand default `return` code from Azure Function

```
return name != null
? (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult($"Hello, {name}")
: new BadRequestObjectResult("Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body");
```

This depending on `name` value will execute:
If `name` is `null`:

```
return new BadRequestObjectResult("Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body");
```

Otherwise:

```
return (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult($"Hello, {name}")
```

My questions:

1. Why there is type casting used for `OkObjectResult` while not for `BadRequestObjectResult`?
2. Why we even need to cast for `OkObjectResult`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you did this...

```cs
if(name != null)
{
  return new OkObjectResult($"Hello, {name}");
}
else
{
  return new BadRequestObjectResult("Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body");
}
```

...casting would not be necessary.

Type casting is necessary on the line of code you have in your question because of its use of the *ternary operator* (i.e. `a ? b : c`).  When using a ternary operator, both elements after the predicate (`b` and `c`) must share a type in common.  `OkObjectResult` and `BadRequestObjectResult` are two different types, so without the cast, this is unacceptable.

However, `b` and `c` both inherit from `ActionResult`.  By casting `OkObjectResult` to `ActionResult`, the `BadRequestObjectResult` element becomes acceptable, because it too is of type `ActionResult`.